# Why it's not thread safety and how to get it thread safety?

Tags: c++, multithreading, fastcgi

There is some function in FCGI called "getRequestContent()". It just gets the data which posted by web browser. So our c++ application is something like a daemon which serves web clients. I think I have some sort of problem with not "thread safety" function:

```
/**
 * Note this is not thread safe due to the static allocation of the
 * content_buffer.
 */
std::string getRequestContent(const FCGX_Request &request)
{
    char *content_length_str = FCGX_GetParam("CONTENT_LENGTH", request.envp);
    unsigned long content_length = STDIN_MAX;
    if (content_length_str)
    {
        content_length = strtol(content_length_str, &content_length_str, 10);
        if (*content_length_str)
        {
            std::cerr << "Can't Parse 'CONTENT_LENGTH='"
                      << FCGX_GetParam("CONTENT_LENGTH", request.envp)
                      << "'. Consuming stdin up to " << STDIN_MAX << "\n";
        }
        if (content_length > STDIN_MAX)
        {
            content_length = STDIN_MAX;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        content_length =
            0;  // Do not read from stdin if CONTENT_LENGTH is missing
    }
    char *content_buffer = new char[content_length];
    std::cin.read(content_buffer, content_length);
    content_length = std::cin.gcount();
    do
        std::cin.ignore(1024);
    while (std::cin.gcount() == 1024);
    std::string content(content_buffer, content_length);
    delete[] content_buffer;
    return content;
}
```

Please explain me why it's not thread safety code? What the sort of a problem we have here? How to get it thread safety? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is, like the comment says, that there is a statically allocated buffer. If two threads would work synchronously on that buffer, you would most likely get race conditions, so you have to avoid that.

That means either fixing `FCGX_GetParam` (which I doubt will be a good idea since it is a third party library) or synchronizing the access to it:

```
//some common mutex
std::mutex mtx;

std::string getRequestContent(const FCGX_Request &request)
{
  std::string content_length_str;
  {
    lock(mtx); //guard every action on the static buffer with this lock
    char *content_length_cptr = FCGX_GetParam("CONTENT_LENGTH", request.envp);
    content_length_str = content_length_cptr; //copy the content of the buffer
  } //unlock the mutex, you dont work on the buffer hence forth  

  unsigned long content_length = 0;
  if (!content_length_str.empty()) try {
    content_length = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned long>(content_length_str);
    if (content_length > STDIN_MAX)
    {
      content_length = STDIN_MAX;
    }
  }
  catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast const&)
  {
    std::cerr << "Can't Parse 'CONTENT_LENGTH='"
              << content_length_str
              << "'. Consuming stdin up to " << STDIN_MAX << "\n";
    content_length = STDIN_MAX;
  }

  // the rest as it was...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But the way is it correctly to declare: std::string content_length_str inside brackets? After next bracket "}" I suppose we can't access to the content_length_str or I'm wrong?

Comment: You're right - it has to be declared outside. I fixed it

Answer (score 3):

```
char * content_length_str = FCGX_GetParam( "CONTENT_LENGTH", request.envp );
```

This line can mean two things:

Either you are leaking memory if the function returns a block allocated by alloc/calloc
OR the function uses a static buffer. That would not be thread safe. Considering the comment, I'd guess it's the second option.

Comment: @JavaRunner you will need to fix FCGX_GetParam.

Comment: OMG :)) Do I need at least "delete content_length_str;" at the end of the getRequestContent function?

Comment: I cannot say, I do not know what FCGX_GetParam does internally. Assuming the current code is correct when running in a single thread, deleting the memory would probably result in a segfault. You could post it in an extra question including the code of FCGX_GetParam if you like.

Comment: synchronizing the access to the unsafe resource is enough. No need to rewrite thirdparty libraries ;)

Comment: @ArneMertz is right, if all calls to this function are in your code and you cannot access the source of this function, syncronizing access would be sufficient.